# Is it possible to see System properties without writing a program?

Tags: java, properties, system

Is it possible to display/print values of system properties **without installing any program**.

I am thinking perhaps one of the programs in jre/bin might do it.

Situation is that there is a locked-down system which is reporting strange values for "os.name" and I cannot install a tool to run.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: There's probably a system tool that can help you - which one however depends on the system you're running. Also: what strange values are being returned?

Comment: [`JVisualVM`](http://visualvm.java.net/overview_tab.html) is part of the jdk and can show the system properties of JVMs running on the same machine. If you want to see the values of no particular JVM you can just look at the system properties of `JVisualVM`’s own JVM.

Comment: @anonymous - In my case Windows but a general solution would be nice.

Comment: @Holger - That looks like it's what I need. Post as an answer and I will accept. Post a pretty screen shot for extra upvotes. Probably more upvotes for a [Freehand Circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/172902)

Comment: Do you have the whole JDK installed or only the JRE?

Comment: @maba - Not sure - is there an alternative to JVisualVM when it is just the JRE available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JVisualVM`](http://visualvm.java.net/overview_tab.html) is part of the jdk and can show the system properties of JVMs running on the same machine. If you want to see the values of no particular JVM you can just look at the system properties of JVisualVM’s own JVM.

[image: With Freehand Circles]

Answer (score 11):

You can print them all using the next command:

```
 java -XshowSettings:all -version
```

Answer (score 2):

This code snipped does print the system properties:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    for (String name : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", name, properties.getProperty(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: The system is locked down - I cannot install anything on the machine in question.

Comment: OP probably only have a JRE and cannot compile any code. And here is some shorter code by the way: `System.getProperties().list(System.out);`.

Comment: +1 @maba: very nice to know :) Do you care if I replace my code with yours in the comment?

Answer (score 2):

Check jconsole. to start jconsole , go inside your installation's bin directory and type ./jconsole on terminal.
I hope it may help you.

Comment: I tried jconsole and couldn't find the system properties. Can you?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon For me, I found them in the MBeans section under java.lang > Runtime > Attributes > SystemProperties.  It is tabular data.  In the "Attribute value" section, double-click the value and you can scroll through the values one row at a time.

Comment: Alternatively, I've been able to show System Properties with an operation: MBeans > com.sun.management > DiagnosticCommand > Operations > vmSystemProperties and click the "vmSystemProperties" button.